# Elementary Algebra exercise

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If $$\sqrt{\overline{192abc}}$$ is a natural number, we have to prove that $$\overline{(a+1)(b+2)c}$$ will be a square number.

I solved the problem, but I would like to see other better solutions. 
My solution:
If $$\sqrt{\overline{192abc}} \in \mathbb{N} \implies \overline{192abc}=k^{2}, k \in \mathbb{N}$$
$$400^{2} < \overline{192abc} <500^{2}$$
$$160.000 < \overline{192abc} <250.000$$, so I tried $$ 445^{2}=198.025 $$, but it was too large so I tried  $$ 440^{2}=193.600 $$ and I spotted that is close to the solution and  I tried $$ 439^{2}=192.721 \implies a=7,\quad b=2,\quad c=1 \implies a+1=8, \quad b+2=4 \implies 841=29^{2}$$ so it's a square number.

Comment: Similar approach, except that I already knew that $440^2 = 193600$, so that made it much easier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a strict solution, you would have to check if maybe smaller numbers than 439 can also be square roots from numbers of the form $\overline{192abc}$. Of course, already 438 is to small for that, as $438^2=191844$.